# Unpacking tuples within a list of lists with specific order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have a long list of lists. The first item in each list is a tuple with four strings. Some of the lists have a second item which is a string:

```
list_one = [('string1', 'number', 'Longstring1', 'long_string2'), 'long_string3']
list_two = [('string5', 'number1', 'Longstring4', 'long_string5')]
```

I would like to loop over each of the lists so that the number string is preferably converted to an integer at the beginning of the list and the remaining items in the tuple are their own list items. If it is not possible to convert the number strings to integers that is okay so long as they are in the first position in the list.So it could hopefully look like this:

```
new_list_one = [number, 'string1', 'Longstring1', 'long_string2', 'long_string3']
new_list_two = [number, 'string5', 'Longstring4', 'long_string5']
```

How can I go about unpacking tuples within a specific order? Would it be most simple for me to use a dictionary with the numbers as the key? My main problem so far has been distinguishing procedures for lists that have the final string outside of the tuple.

Comment: Is the string to be converted to integer always in the same position? or you need to find it?

Comment: The integer is always in the same position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list_one = [('string1', '100', 'Longstring1', 'long_string2'), 'long_string3']
list_two = [('string5', '200', 'Longstring4', 'long_string5')]
```

You can unpack the tuple, switch the first and second element, and attempt to convert to and `int`

```
def int_if_possible(val):
    try:
        return int(val)
    except ValueError:
        return val

def unpack(l):
    ret = [*l[0], *l[1:]]
    ret[0], ret[1] = int_if_possible(ret[1]), ret[0]
    return ret

print(unpack(list_one))
# [100, 'string1', 'Longstring1', 'long_string2', 'long_string3']
print(unpack(list_two))
# [200, 'string5', 'Longstring4', 'long_string5']
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. Do you know of a page online that can help me understand how the asterisks in unpack() work? I'm not familiar with the notation.

Comment: @JackReimer [Here's one of the PEPs that descibe the unary `*` operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/).  The other use is in function definintions: `def foo(**bar): print(bar)` takes any number of `bar` arguments and puts them in a tuple.  So `foo(1, 2, 3)` would print `(1, 2, 3)`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from you explanation:

- the second element of the tuple is always an integer
- the tuple has always 4 elements
- the list has some times only one more element

If these are fixed rules you can be explicit and simple.

```
def trans(lst):
    ret = [int(lst[0][1]), lst[0][0], lst[0][2], lst[0][3]]
    if len(lst) == 2:
        ret.append(lst[1])
    return ret
```

Obs.: the `*` operator don't work in lists in Python 2.7.